# unable to stop a docker container running on my mac

Tags: docker

I am unable to stop a docker container running on my mac. after stoping this container it always pops up.

Here is the logs

```sh
(base) ➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
e4258d657c8d        quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:latest   "/bin/prometheus --c…"   4 minutes ago       Up 4 minutes        9090/tcp            monitoring_prometheus.1.wrps0j1w9m4jz82fec9d71xiu
(base) ➜  ~
(base) ➜  ~
(base) ➜  ~ docker stop e4258d657c8d
e4258d657c8d
(base) ➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND             CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
(base) ➜  ~ docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                                  COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
4bfb8f9ea862        quay.io/prometheus/prometheus:latest   "/bin/prometheus --c…"   9 seconds ago       Up 2 seconds        9090/tcp            monitoring_prometheus.1.rw1tpoi92052rfgsgxt4mm2ll
(base) ➜
```

Comment: Tried `docker kill` instead?

Answer (score 1):

You've deployed the container using swarm mode and it will automatically recover from any deviation from the target state. To change the target state, delete the service (or entire stack):

```
docker service rm monitoring_prometheus

docker stack rm monitoring
```

Comment: @Rajeevkumar glad it helped. Make sure to check the answer to mark your question as answered.